# Python flask on downloading zip file gets corrupted

Tags: python, flask, zip, runtime-error, unzip

I have written following python flask code to download zip file.

```
@ns.route('/zip_file_download', strict_slashes=False)
class ZipDownload(Resource):
  def get(self):
     output_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), './out'))
     out_file_name = os.path.join(output_path, 'sample.zip')
     r = send_file(out_file_name, mimetype='application/octet-stream', 
     attachment_filename='sample.zip', as_attachment=True)
    return r
```

This downloads the zip file but on extracting the zip file it gives an error - Error - 21 - is not a directory - Unable to expand probably because it gets corrupted. I also tried with send_from_directory but the same error crept there too. I am developing this on Mac machine but the downloaded files are also corrupted when opened on windows or an other OS. Any suggestions?

PS:  Moreover, this issue is only happening when running the API from a Mac machine. Things seem to be fine when ran from windows on linux machine. It's quite peculiar.

Comment: Found this on web: https://pythonprogramming.net/flask-send-file-tutorial/
have you tried that?

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. The only reason you are getting a faulty .zip is either its corrupt from source, or there is something wrong in your path (`out_file_name`). Use `print()` function to print the path on the console before sending the response, and check whether its correct.

Comment: The path is correct. I have already checked that. Also the file at the source is correct. Moreover, this issue is only happening when running the API from a Mac machine. Things seem to be fine when ran from windows on linux machine. It's quite peculiar.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using flask-restplus and are using the older version upgrade it to the latest version, this worked for me.

Comment: Yes, I used flask-restplus 0.10.1v initially and it was not working and it worked after upgrading to flask-restplus 0.12.1